# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push') in an onClick function

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, mern

I am getting error in this code while using an onclick function for routing in it I don't understand that how to fix it.

```
import React from "react";
import { Row, Col, Container, Button, ButtonGroup } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import OrderList from "../components/Admin/Orderlist";
import Pizzaslist from "../components/Admin/Pizzaslist";
import Userlist from "../components/Admin/Userlist";
import AddNewPizza from "../components/Admin/AddNewPizza"
const AdminScreen = ({ history }) => {
 
  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <h1 className="text-center bg-dark text-light p-2">Admin Panel</h1>
          <Col md={2}>
            <ButtonGroup vertical style={{ minHeight: "400px" }}>
              <Button onClick={() => history.push("/admin/userlist")}>
                All Users
              </Button>
              <Button onClick={() => history.push("/admin/pizzalist")}>
                All Pizzas
              </Button>
              <Button onClick={() => history.push("/admin/addnewpizza")}>
                Add New Pizza
              </Button>
              <Button onClick={() => history.push("/admin/orderlist")}>
                All Orders
              </Button>
            </ButtonGroup>
          </Col>
          <Col md={10}>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/admin" component={Userlist} exact />
              <Route path="/admin/userlist" component={Userlist} exact />              
              <Route path="/admin/pizzalist" component={Pizzaslist} exact />
              <Route path="/admin/addnewpizza" component={AddNewPizza} exact />
              <Route path="/admin/orderlist" component={OrderList} exact />
            </Routes>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default AdminScreen;
```

Comment: This code is not sufficient to analyze the reason why you are getting the error. You will need to share the code where you are passing the history object to the `AdminScreen` component. From what I read, the error is thrown because the history object has its value as undefined.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You have to console `history` and then check in history if the`props` is coming or not.

Comment: Which version of `react-router` you're using? You can find that in package.json file in your project

Comment: If you're using react-router v5, you can try : `let history = useHistory();` and import it by `import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";` and remove the `history` prop from `AdminScreen`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `Routes` component then you are using `react-router-dom@6` which means there is no `history` object to reference, no `history` is passed as a prop to this `AdminScreen` component, and the `Route` component is using the old v5 APIs and needs to be updated.

1. Use the `useNavigate` hook to access the `navigate` function to be used in the click handlers.
2. Update the `Route` components to render the routed content on the `element` prop as a `React.ReactNode`, e.g. as JSX.

Code

```
import React from "react";
import { Row, Col, Container, Button, ButtonGroup } from "react-bootstrap";
import {
  Routes,
  Route,
  useNavigate // <-- import hook
} from "react-router-dom";
import OrderList from "../components/Admin/Orderlist";
import Pizzaslist from "../components/Admin/Pizzaslist";
import Userlist from "../components/Admin/Userlist";
import AddNewPizza from "../components/Admin/AddNewPizza";

const AdminScreen = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate(); // <-- call hook

  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <h1 className="text-center bg-dark text-light p-2">Admin Panel</h1>
```

Replace `history.push` with `navigate` to effect a PUSH navigation action.

```
        <Col md={2}>
          <ButtonGroup vertical style={{ minHeight: "400px" }}>
            <Button onClick={() => navigate("/admin/userlist")}>
              All Users
            </Button>
            <Button onClick={() => navigate("/admin/pizzalist")}>
              All Pizzas
            </Button>
            <Button onClick={() => navigate("/admin/addnewpizza")}>
              Add New Pizza
            </Button>
            <Button onClick={() => navigate("/admin/orderlist")}>
              All Orders
            </Button>
          </ButtonGroup>
        </Col>
```

Update the `Route` component to use correct props.

```
        <Col md={10}>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/admin" element={<Userlist />} />
            <Route path="/admin/userlist" element={<Userlist />} />              
            <Route path="/admin/pizzalist" element={<Pizzaslist />} />
            <Route path="/admin/addnewpizza" element={<AddNewPizza />} />
            <Route path="/admin/orderlist" element={<OrderList />} />
          </Routes>
        </Col>
```

```
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default AdminScreen;
```